# Instanced model rendering, missing hardwareinstancing in effects.techniques

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I have been trying to get hardware instancing working in XNA 4. I have been following a Microsoft sample code and have everything working until the last couple lines of code.

The problem I am having is the the effect.Techniques only has basic effect in it. when I compile and run their source code it has the hardware instancing option, just not in what I copied over. It may have something to do with the InstancedModelPipeline that their project has, but I cant find how it actually gets linked in to the project. Their InstancedModelPipeline pulls in a InstancedModel.fx that has HardwareInstancing in it.

```
Effect effect = meshPart.Effect;

effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["HardwareInstancing"];
effect.Parameters["World"].SetValue(modelBones[mesh.ParentBone.Index]);
effect.Parameters["View"].SetValue(Camera.ViewMatrix);
effect.Parameters["Projection"].SetValue(projection);
```

[SampleCode Site](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/mesh_instancing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InstancedModelPipeline` is a content pipeline extension. To use it you must right click on your *content* project, click "Add Reference", and then select the `InstancedModelPipeline` project.

[image: InstancedModelPipeline in the content project reference list]

(Note: don't reference content pipeline extensions from your *game* project.)

The `InstancedModelPipeline` project makes a new content processor for models available, called `InstancedModelProcessor`. You must select your model in your content project, go to the Properties panel (F4), and set your model to use this processor.

[image: InstancedModelProcessor selected]

The default XNA model processor will build `BasicEffect` into the model (the `ModelMeshPart.Effect` properties). This content processor will build in `InstancedModel.fx` instead, which includes the `HardwareInstancing` effect you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you So much! I was banging my head on this for several hours last night!

Comment: Is there a way to automatically set every model to use the instanced model processor or do you have to set each one manually?

Comment: @FreakinaBox I think you might be able to multi-select them in the solution explorer (ctrl-click) and set the properties on all of them at once. Or edit the `.contentproj` file in a text editor if you need to be more heavy-duty about it.